# Transforming data in Google Sheets/Excel by string in column name

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup, index-match

Okay so I have some data like this:

**tableA**

```
cohort   q1   value_JAMES  value_PETER value_JOHN
     A    1          col1   col1, col2     
     A    2    col1, col2   col1, col2       col2     
     B    1                 col1, col2 col1, col2
```

So these are the values coming in in its raw form.

I would like to make them look different....

I have a repeating list which looks like:

- Repeating list of 1-3 with the names represented in each
- col1 and col2 empty.

**tableB**

```
q1  NAME    col1    col2
 1 JAMES
 1 PETER
 1  JOHN
 2 JAMES
 2 PETER
 2  JOHN
 3 JAMES
 3 PETER
 3  JOHN
```

I would like to transform the data with the following criteria

- Take only cohort A
- Fill them into the empty table (tableB)
- If NAME appears in tableA's column name, then match it to table B (they will always match exact) by name AND q1.
- Represent via binary on if it appeared or not.

Final result:

```
q1  NAME    col1    col2
 1 JAMES       1       0
 1 PETER       1       1
 1  JOHN       0       0
 2 JAMES       1       1
 2 PETER       1       1
 2  JOHN       0       1 
 3 JAMES
 3 PETER
 3  JOHN
```

Comment: Why Col2 is `0` in your desired result as cohort `A` has `Col1,Col2` in second column in first row in raw data?

Comment: Please pick one per question google sheets or excel

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets-formula/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in cell `C2`:

`=sign( iferror( filter( 'Form Data'!$A$2:$A$6, 'Form Data'!$C$2:$C$6 = $A2, 'Form Data'!$B$2:$B$6 = $B2, search(C$1, 'Form Data'!$D$2:$D$6 & 'Form Data'!$E$2:$E$6 & 'Form Data'!$F$2:$F$6) ) ) )`

Then copy down and to the right.